# activiti servicetask delegateExpression error

Tags: activiti

```
protected ServiceTask createServiceTask(String id, String name, String ref) {
        ServiceTask serviceTask = new ServiceTask();
        serviceTask.setId(id);
        serviceTask.setName(name);
        serviceTask.setImplementation(ref);
        serviceTask.setImplementationType(ImplementationType.IMPLEMENTATION_TYPE_DELEGATEEXPRESSION);
        return serviceTask;
    }

public class ServiceTaskDelegate implements JavaDelegate {
    @Autowired
    private RepositoryService repositoryService;

    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution delegateExecution) {
        System.out.println("service task execute");
        System.out.println(repositoryService);
    }
}
```

When I use ImplementationType = ImplementationType.IMPLEMENTATION_TYPE_CLASS is ok
, but repositoryService==null,

so I use ImplementationType = ImplementationType.IMPLEMENTATION_TYPE_DELEGATEEXPRESSION
throw out

```
Caused by: org.activiti.engine.ActivitiIllegalArgumentException: Delegate expression com.test.activiti.ServiceTaskDelegate did neither resolve to an implementation of interface org.activiti.engine.impl.delegate.ActivityBehavior nor interface org.activiti.engine.delegate.JavaDelegate
```

springboot2.0/activit6.0

Comment: springboot2.0 In order to solve the problem of injection null

Comment: Please format your question, make your question more readable.

Answer (score 0):

1. Spring support *@Autowired* only for Spring Beans. Normally a Java Class become a Spring Bean when it is created by Spring, but not by *new*.
2. If you want to use *ImplementationType.IMPLEMENTATION_TYPE_DELEGATEEXPRESSION*, you should change implemented interface to *ActivityBehavior*

Comment: I have tried it before I sent this question. The result is the same. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

于是我还是用了ImplementationType.IMPLEMENTATION_TYPE_CLASS
但是在获取bean的方式上不用@autowired 而是自己写了getBean的方法 代码如下:

```
@Component
public class SpringUtils implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext = null;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        if(SpringUtils.applicationContext == null){
            SpringUtils.applicationContext  = applicationContext;
        }
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }

    public static Object getBean(String name){
        return getApplicationContext().getBean(name);

    }

    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> clazz){
        return getApplicationContext().getBean(clazz);
    }

    public static <T> T getBean(String name, Class<T> clazz){
        return getApplicationContext().getBean(name, clazz);
    }

}
```

这样我就可以通过RuntimeService runtimeService = SpringUtils.getBean(RuntimeService.class);获取RuntimeService